# Correct way to edit a database service after first initiation

Tags: php, mysql, database, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I use two different database services in my Phalcon application.

- db: Global database with system-wide data, including accounts and users
- db_data: This database hosts customer-specific data. The database-name is different for each customer/account. This is determined when the customer sign in.

This works in the web application, when I have one account active. Now I have a cronjob, that is going to loop through a table in the global "db" database. And after it is going to connect to the specific "db_data" database.

This works for the first account, but after this it will not connect to the new database. It still use the first initiated database.

The db_data service is a shared service in the services.php:

```
$di->set('db_data', function () use ($config, $di) {
        if(!$di->getCore()->getAccount()) {
                throw new \MyNamespace\Exception(_('Account is not set. Can not load account database.'));
        }
        $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');
        $dbListener = new \MyNamespace\Module\Core\Helper\Model\DatabaseListener();
        $eventsManager->attach('db_data', $dbListener);
    $connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        'host' => $config->database->host,
        'username' => $config->database->username,
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'dbname' => $config->database->data_dbname_prefix.$di->getCore()->getAccount()->id,
        'name' => 'data',
    ));
        $connection->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
        return $connection;
}, true);
```

In the first model in "db" i have the following in the initialize() function:

```
$this->setConnectionService('db');
```

In the second model in "db_data" i have the following in the initialize() function:

```
$this->setConnectionService('db_data');
```

Here is an example of the cron PHP-file:

```
$screens = \MyNamespace\Module\DigitalSignage\Model\Screen::find(array(
    'conditions' => 'deleted_at IS NULL',
));

foreach($screens as $screen) {
    $console->getDi()->getCore()->setAccount(\MyNamespace\Module\Core\Model\Account::findFirst('id='.$screen->account_id));
    $campaign = \MyNamespace\Module\DigitalSignage\Model\Campaign::findFirst(array(
            'conditions' => 'id = :id: AND account_id = :account_id: AND deleted_at IS NULL',
            'bind' => array(
                'id' => $screen->digitalsignage_campaign_id,
                'account_id' => $console->getDi()->getCore()->getAccount()->id,
            ),
        ));

    var_dump($campaign);
}
```

What is the correct way to change the database service parameteres after first initiation?

Phalcon version: 3.2.2 PHP version: 7.0.22

Comment: Have you tried `$connection->connect();` before your return?

Comment: Also have you tried leaving off `,true` so it's not shared? If you need it shared, it's more readable to use `setShared` instead of `set`. Shared means it acts like a singleton.

Comment: At first it was not shared, and I set the service to shared to test it. I added `$connection->connect()` to the service now, and tried both to set the service as shared and not. Still same problem.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->setConnectionService('db_data');$this->setSchema('db_data');`?

Comment: I have `$this->setConnectionService('db_data');` in my model, but not `$this->setSchema('db_‌​data');` I tried adding that now, but get the error `Table 'db_data'.'digitalsignage_campaign' doesn't exist in database when dumping meta-data for`. I think I will go for a PHP cronjob that spawn separate processes for each "account"/database. It is a bit more time- and resource consuming, but that will do the trick for me. I have a colleague that checked the Zepire source code. And it seems there is a problem with PDO that can not change connection settings after first setup.